# Aggregated error SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 select 
person.firstname, 
person.lastname, 
sum(order_item.pricecharged) as [sales]
from person cross join order_item
join ORDERS
on ORDERS.EmployeeID = PERSON.PersonID
group by person.firstname
```

getting an error of:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Column 'person.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

(apologize still new to SQL queries)

Comment: This looks more like tsql or sql-server to me

Comment: You need to add person.lastname into the group by list.

Comment: that error message confirms it is T-SQL so I removed MySQL as a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what is wrong - you can't have a column in the select list (specifically person.lastname) that is not in the group by list unless is has an aggregate function on it. You are saying group by firstname, then add last name to the output.  What if you have Bob Jones and Bob Smith - the sales for both will be summed together, but you haven't told SQL what to do with the surname, so it errors.

In this case, you probably want to change the group line by to

```
group by person.firstname, person.lastname
```

Answer (score 2):

Do exactly what the error message tells you, place all the "non-aggregating" columns into the group by clause:

```
SELECT
      person.firstname                         -- this is "non-aggregating"
    , person.lastname                          -- this is "non-aggregating"
    , SUM(order_item.pricecharged) AS [sales]  -- this is "aggregating"
FROM person
CROSS JOIN order_item
JOIN ORDERS ON ORDERS.EmployeeID = PERSON.PersonID
GROUP BY
      person.firstname
    , person.lastname
```